# mongoose Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

this is my section

```
{
   create:123455,
   audio:5218,
   question:{
       subject : 5
   }
}
```

then I want to add a url array in question like

```
{
   create:123455,
   audio:5218,
   question:{
       subject : 5,
       url:["aaaaaaaaa"]
   }
}
```

I have tried to use

```
this.findOneAndUpdate({
    answerID: id            
}, {
    $addToSet:{question:{imgUrl:url}}
}, {
    upsert:true
}).exec(cb);
```

When I run the function there is someting error

```
Cannot apply $addToSet modifier to non-array\n
```

this is my mongoose model

```
var AnswerSchema = new Schema({

    audio: {type: String},
    created: { type: Number },
    question: {
        imgUrl: { type: Array },
        subject: { type: String },
    },

});
```

Comment: `$set:{question:{imgUrl.$:url}}`   like this?  @user3100115

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the ["dot notation"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#dot-notation)

```
Model.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'answerID': id },
    { '$addToSet': { 'question.imgUrl': /* your new value */ } },
    { upsert: true }
).exec(cb);
```